# Semisimplicity of restriction: Representation theory

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $E$ be a vector space over field $K$ and $\rho : G \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}(E)$ a semisimple $K$-representation of $G$. Let $H \lhd G$ be a finite-index normal subgroup of $G$.

How do I show that $\operatorname{Res}^G_H(\rho)$, a restriction of $G$ to $H$ is also semisimple as a representation of $H$?

Comment: I don't think this is true in general. Take $\mathbb{Z}_3 \triangleleft S_3$ and restrict the 2-dimensional irreducible representation of $S_3$. It will be the direct sum of two 1-dimensional representations since $\mathbb{Z}_3$ is abelian.

Comment: @Turion that is semisimple.

Comment: True, no idea what I was thinking those 8 years ago.