# Restriction $\mathrm{Res}_{H}^{G}(\rho)$ of semisimple representation $\rho: G \to GL(E)$ is semisimple, $[G:H] < \infty$, $H \triangleleft G$

Tags: representation-theory

This question has already been asked here: [Group representation is semisimple iff restriction to subgroup of finite index is semisimple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2744045/group-representation-is-semisimple-iff-restriction-to-subgroup-of-finite-index-i), but only one direction of the proof is provided. I'm asking here about the other one. Also, this question, [Semisimplicity of restriction: Representation theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596254/semisimplicity-of-restriction-representation-theory), asks the same as mine, but I don't understand the comment by Turion: if the restriction will be the direct sum of $2$ $1$-dimensional representations, won't it also be semisimple, as a direct sum of $2$ irreducible representations? Namely:

> If $G$ is a group, $k$ a field, $E$ a $k$-vector space, $\rho: G \to GL(E)$ a semisimple linear representation, $H \triangleleft G$, $[G : H] < +\infty$. Prove (or disprove!) that $\pi := \mathrm{Res}_{H}^{G}(\rho)$ given by $\pi(h)v = \rho(h)v$ is also semisimple.

The hint for the exercise in the book An Introduction to the Representation Theory of Groups by Emmanuel Kowalski gives the following hint: One can assume that $\rho$ is irreducible - show that there exists a *maximal* **semisimple** subrepresentation of $\pi$.

So as soon as I saw "maximal", I thought about Zorn's lemma. The problem is, I have no idea how to use the finiteness of the index **or** the irreducibility of $\rho$. Here's what I came up with: let $\mathcal{M}$ denote the set of all semisimple subrepresentations of $\pi$. $0 \in \mathcal{M}$ so $\mathcal{M}$ is non-empty. Then, let $\mathcal{L} = \lbrace \sigma_{\alpha}: H \to GL(E_{\alpha}) \rbrace_{\alpha \in A}$ be a chain in $\mathcal{M}$. Then obviously $\sigma: H \to GL(\bigcup_{\alpha \in A}E_{\alpha})$ is a subrepresentation of $E$. So now my idea was to show that $\sigma$ is completely reducible.

Let $F_{1} \leq \bigcup_{\alpha \in A}E_{\alpha}$ be a subrepresentation. Then $F_{1} \cap E_{\alpha}$ is also a subrepresentation of $E_{\alpha}$, so by semisimplicity, i.e. complete reducibility of $E_{\alpha}$ there exists a subrepresentation $F_{\alpha} \leq E_{\alpha}$ such that $F_{1} \cap E_{\alpha} \oplus F_{\alpha} = E_{\alpha}.$ I'd like to take $F_{2} := \bigcup_{\alpha \in A} F_{\alpha}$ and show $\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} E_{\alpha} = F_{1} \oplus F_{2}$.

**The problem:** $\lbrace F_{\alpha} \rbrace_{\alpha \in A}$ is not a chain, so I don't even know that $F_{2}$ would be a vector subspace. I **could** take $F_{2} = \sum_{\alpha \in A} F_{\alpha}$, but I wouldn't know that $F_{1} \cap F_{2} = 0$.

**Another problem:** I have no idea how to use the fact that $H$ has finite index in $G$ or that $\rho$ is irreducible, which probably tells me I'm not on the right track.

Can anyone give me an explanation of what a proof of this statement would look like, or in case the statement is false, an explanation of why it's false?